# Powershell: Directory file structure into JSON

Tags: json, powershell, hashtable

Hello I am new to PowerShell. I have a filepath which is 4 level.

Rootedirectory\directory1\directory2\directory3\ files

The filestructure always remains the same.

Here is my code, the issue is it's repeating the same values

```
#Place Root Folder in desktop
$Fullpath = 'C:\Users\Glen Sale\Desktop\donor'
$rootDir = $Fullpath.Split('\')[4]

#Get Creationtime of matching root folder
$session = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Glen Sale\Desktop' -Filter $rootDir



    $organfolder = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Glen Sale\Desktop\donor' -Directory 
foreach ($dir in $organfolder){
    Get-ChildItem $dir.FullName -File 
    $biospyfolder = Get-ChildItem $dir.FullName -Directory
    foreach($dir2 in $biospyfolder){
        gci $dir2.fullname -File
        $sectionfolder = gci $biospyfolder.fullname -Directory
        foreach($dir3 in $sectionfolder){
           $tiffFiles= gci $dir3.fullname -File
        }
    }
}


function recurse {

    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Fullpath   |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $Obj = [ordered]@{
             session_id = $session.CreationTime | Get-Date -f ("yyyyMMdd") 
             session_date = $session.CreationTime | Get-Date -f ("yyyy/MM/dd") 
                #$rootDir 
                organ=@{ 
                     organ_id= $organfolder.namer#[0]
                        biospy= @( 
                            @{biospy_id = $biospyfolder.name#[0]
                                section= @(
                                    @{section_id= $sectionfolder.name#[0]
                                      tiff_files = $tiffFiles.name#[0]  
                                    }
                                )
                        })
           }
        }
    } {
        $Obj
    }
}


recurse  | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 #| out-file ''
```

The output I am getting is being repated.
Results:

```
[
    {
        "session_id":  "20210418",
        "session_date":  "2021/04/18",
        "organ":  {
                      "organ_id":  [
                                       "FBG01",
                                       "FBG02"
                                   ],
                      "biospy":  [
                                     {
                                         "biospy_id":  "FBG01.12.1",
                                         "section":  [
                                                         {
                                                             "section_id":  [
                                                                                "FBG01.12.1.1",
                                                                                "FBG01.12.1.2"
                                                                            ],
                                                             "tiff_files":  [
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d0.TIF",
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d1.TIF",
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d2.TIF",
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d3.TIF",
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f01d0.TIF",
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f01d1.TIF"
                                                                            ]
                                                         }
                                                     ]
                                     }
                                 ]
                  }
    },
    {
        "session_id":  "20210418",
        "session_date":  "2021/04/18",
        "organ":  {
                      "organ_id":  [
                                       "FBG01",
                                       "FBG02"
                                   ],
                      "biospy":  [
                                     {
                                         "biospy_id":  "FBG01.12.1",
                                         "section":  [
                                                         {
                                                             "section_id":  [
                                                                                "FBG01.12.1.1",
                                                                                "FBG01.12.1.2"
                                                                            ],
                                                             "tiff_files":  [
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d0.TIF",
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d1.TIF",
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d2.TIF",
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d3.TIF",
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f01d0.TIF",
                                                                                "No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f01d1.TIF"
                                                                            ]
                                                         }
                                                     ]
                                     }
                                 ]
                  }
    }
]
```

These is the result that I want which is categorize correctly

```
{
  "session_id": "20210409",
  "session_date": "2021/04/09",
  "organ": {
    "organ_id": "FBG01",
    "biopsy": [
      {
        "biopsy_id": "FBG01.12.1",
        "section": [
          {
            "section_id": "FBG01.12.1.1",
            "tiff_files": [
              "FBG01 12 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f00d0.TIF",
              "FBG01 12 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f01d0.TIF",
              "FBG01 12 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f02d0.TIF"
            ]
          },
          {
            "section_id": "FBG01.12.1.2",
            "tiff_files": [
              "FBG01 12 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f20d0.TIF",
              "FBG01 12 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f21d0.TIF",
              "FBG01 12 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f22d0.TIF"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "biopsy_id": "FBG01.18.1",
        "section": [
          {
            "section_id": "FBG01.18.1.1",
            "tiff_files": [
              "FBG01 12 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f00d0.TIF",
              "FBG01 12 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f01d0.TIF",
              "FBG01 12 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f02d0.TIF"
            ]
          },
          {
            "section_id": "FBG01.18.1.2",
            "tiff_files": [
              "FBG01 18 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f20d0.TIF",
              "FBG01 18 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f21d0.TIF",
              "FBG01 18 hr_Bottom Slide_R_p01_0_A01f22d0.TIF"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you need to see what the directory looks like

```
C:\USERS\GLEN SALE\DESKTOP\DONOR
+---FBG01
|   \---FBG01.12.1
|       +---FBG01.12.1.1
|       |       No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f02d3.TIF
|       |       No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f03d0.TIF
|       |       No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f03d1.TIF
|       |       No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f03d2.TIF
|       |       No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f03d3.TIF
|       |       
|       \---FBG01.12.1.2
|               No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d0.TIF
|               No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d1.TIF
|               No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d2.TIF
|               No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d3.TIF
|               No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f01d0.TIF
|               No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f01d1.TIF
|               
\---FBG02
    \---FBG01.12.1
        +---FBG01.12.1.1
        |       No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f02d3.TIF
        |       No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f03d0.TIF
        |       No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f03d1.TIF
        |       No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f03d2.TIF
        |       No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f03d3.TIF
        |       
        \---FBG01.12.1.2
                No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d0.TIF
                No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d1.TIF
                No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d2.TIF
                No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f00d3.TIF
                No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f01d0.TIF
                No Sample 0.05 40X_Bottom Slide_R_p00_0_A01f01d1.TIF
```

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the way you write your recurse function because `Foreach-object` has a special syntax.

Look at :

```
1..3| foreach-object {$n=0}{$a=$n++}{$a}
```

gives  :

```
3
```

First script block is initiator executed once before the loop, second is the loop executed as many times as the number of objects and the third executed once at the end.

But you are using just two

```
1..3| foreach-object {$a=$n++}{$a}
```

which gives :

```
3
3
3
```

First script block initiator executed once and the loop `{$obj}` executed multiple times.

Comment: how would i add that in my code or proper way of doing so

Comment: I copy pasted your edit. it seems to be throwing Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline

Comment: and others I found the solution posting my answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to my issue using class and nested loop

```
class section
{
    [System.String]$section_id = ''
    [System.String[]]$tiff_files = @()
}
class biopsy
{
    [System.String]$biopsy_id = ''
    [section[]]$section = @()
}
class organ
{
    [System.String]$organ_id = ''
    [biopsy[]]$biopsy = @()
}
class session
{
    [System.String]$session_id = ''
    [System.String]$session_date = ''
    [organ[]]$organ = @()
}

 

$session = [session]@{
    session_id = 'session_id'
    session_date = 'session_date'
}
foreach($o in Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path C:\Users\v-mtouri\Desktop\donor)
{
    $organ = [organ]@{organ_id = $o.Name}
    $session.organ += $organ
    foreach ($b in Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $o.FullName)
    {
        $biopsy = [biopsy]@{biopsy_id = $b.Name}
        $organ.biopsy += $biopsy
        foreach ($s in Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $b.FullName)
        {
            $section = [section]@{
                section_id = $s.Name
                tiff_files = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $s.FullName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
            }
            $biopsy.section += $section
        }
    }
}

 

$session | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```